# Как правильно установить outputPath для file-loader?

Tags: webpack, path

К процессу сборки в webpack подключил file-loader таким образом.

```
    {
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
                    name: "[name].[ext]",
                    outputPath: "img",
                    useRelativePath: true,
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        mozjpeg: {
          progressive: true,
          quality: 65
        },
        optipng: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        pngquant: {
          quality: '65-90',
          speed: 4
        },
        gifsicle: {
          interlaced: false,
        },
        svgo: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

До обработки, картинки лежат по такому пути:

```
--src
----img
------logo.jpg
------backgrounds
--------img1.jpg
--------img2.jpg
------icons
--------icon1.svg
--------icon2.svg
```

После обработки картинки сохранятся по такому пути, т.е. не сохраняется структура:

```
--dist
----img
------logo.jpg
------img1.jpg
------img2.jpg
------icon1.svg
------icon2.svg
```

Пробовал делать вот так:
`name: "[folder]/[name].[ext]"`,

Все картинки по внутренних папках сохраняются верно, т.е. структура сохраняется, но для тех картинок, которые были первоначально в `src/img`, создается папка в `dist/img`, т.е. получается так `dist/img/img/logo.png`

Для того чтобы было понятнее:

```
--dist
----img
------img
--------logo.jpg
------backgrounds
--------img1.jpg
--------img2.jpg
------icons
--------icon1.svg
--------icon2.svg
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вместо `[folder]` попробуй использовать `[path]` (слеш надо будет опустить)
2. Когда используешь `[path]` или `[folder]` не используй `outputPath: "img",` у тебя дальше `useRelativePath: true,`

P.S. В случае есть будешь использовать `[path][name].[ext]` возможно потребуется опустить опцию `useRelativePath: true,`

Пример:

```
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
```

Перенос в конкретную папку с сохранением структуры:

```
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'dist/[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
```

Может ссылка на примеры поможет: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#examples

Comment: Образуется вот такая структура dist/src/img и только тут что нужно, по какой-то причине оно в создает в папке dist папку src http://prntscr.com/nd2bz5

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi я чуть чуть запутался. :) Можете уточнить? Папка dist напрягает?

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавив пример. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

В опции `name` укажите `'[path][name].[ext]'`, а `outputPath` и `useRelativePath` уберите.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим что вспомогательных файлы лежат в

> src/assets

В **папке assets** у тебя есть папки fonts, image, и пр.

> src/assets/fonts/Roboto.ttf
>
> src/assets/images/background/background.png

Главная строка здесь **options** " file-loader "

```
{
  test: /(\.svg|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.woff2?|\.eot|\.ttf|\.otf)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: file => {
      let dirNameInsideAssets = path.relative(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'assets'), path.dirname(file));
      return `${dirNameInsideAssets}/[name].[ext]`;
    }
  }
}
```

Тогда на выходе ты получишь:

> dist/fonts/Roboto.ttf
>
> dist/images/background/background.png

Можно сказать **папка assets теряется**, но думаю суть ты понял.

Comment: [Источник](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/261#issuecomment-576061837)